# Text is not wrapped inside div container with word-wrap

Tags: css, word-wrap, tablerow, css-tables

I have a situation like this : http://jsfiddle.net/uG4b5/
Anybody can help me why the text inside div.content is not wrapped to the width defined in the div.container?

This is what I want to achieve : 
[image]

For a reason I have to keep the table based layout there. So I can't remove the display: table-row; nor display: table-cell;

Thanks

Comment: dude i suppose its coming correctly, try changing width and test

Comment: Hi @sij, I have added an image to help explain what I want achieve. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove word-wrap: break-all property and use table, tr, th, td tags instead ...

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uG4b5/4/

Comment: Unfortunately I have to keep the table based layout there :(

Comment: thanks but your demo still not working. but it doesn't work with long word without spaces